# How to install tcpdump on Cloud Linux

Tags: linux, ssh, tcpdump

I am new on Linux, and I own a server with Cloud Linux installed.

What I like to do is  to install the tcpdump but I cannot.

I have try to execute the following command from SSH:

```
yum install tcpdump
```

But I am getting the following message:

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, rhnplugin
Profilename: myserver.host.ext
Not licensed
There was an error communicating with CLN.
CLN support will be disabled.

Error Message:
    Service not enabled for system profile: "myserver.host.ext"
Error Class Code: 31
Error Class Info: 
    This system does not have a valid entitlement for Red Hat Network.
    Please visit https://cln.cloudlinux.com/rhn/systems/SystemEntitlements.do
    or login at https://cln.cloudlinux.com, and from the "Overview" tab,
 select "Subscription Management" to enable RHN service for this system.
Explanation:
    Your organization does not have enough Management entitlements to register this
    system to CloudLinux Network. Please notify your organization administrator of this error. 
    You should be able to register this system after your organization frees existing 
    or purchases additional entitlements. Additional entitlements may be purchased by your
    organization administrator by logging into CloudLinux Network and visiting
    the 'Subscription Management' page in the 'Your RHN' section of RHN.

    A common cause of this error code is due to having mistakenly setup an
    Activation Key which is set as the universal default.  If an activation key is set
    on the account as a universal default, you can disable this key and retry to avoid
    requiring a Management entitlement.
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
cr                                                                                                                               | 2.9 kB     00:00     
Setting up Install Process
No package tcpdump available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

So, Is there a way to install tcpdump on cloud linux ? and how ?

Kind regards !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it seems that your Cloud linux server is not registered yet. You probably need to register it first before installing packet using yum. Check this documentation about how to register your Cloud linux server http://docs.cloudlinux.com/registering_cloudlinux_server.html